# Print odd or even numbers within the range accepted from user

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

[image]here it prints both odd and even numbers from the range 10.. why??

i want to print only user requested type of number..not both odd and even numbers
if the user requested odd then print odd numbers within the given range..
same as in the case of even

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Complete waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprise you're not getting an error.
First your choice is a char array of size 10 and you're comparing the last item (technically the item after last) to 2 chars that have not been initialized. this is just wrong. also use if and else when the choice are mutually exclusive.
one more thing, name your variables reasonably.
something like the code below would work better

```c
int limit, choice;
printf("enter the limit\n");
scanf("%d",limit);
printf("enter 1 for odd, 2 for even\n");
scanf("%d", choice);
if(choice == 1){
//do your odd loop
..
}else {
//do your other loop
}
```

we can also check that the input is either 1 or 2.
anyway best of luck.